# How can I get other Titans during the Beta?

Tags: titanfall

I've seen some people in the fast Titan during the beta and heard them talk about the armored Titan; how can I get them during the beta?  Is there any guaranteed way other than the randomly dropped burn cards?

Comment: I've gotten to the level cap on beta and no other titans have unlocked, and the Titan select screen doesn't show any that can be. I think burn cards are probably the only option, if they are one, but I've not seen any that change your Titan chassis or seen any titans other than the basic one afaik.

Answer (score 3):

In the full game you can select the types of titans in customization. However, in the Beta you could only select the Atlas. The Titans are:

- Atlas - Attack type, balanced armor and mobility. Its ability core doubles damage for a short time
- Stryder - Mobility type, low armor high mobility. Its ability core allows for unlimited dashing for a short time
- Ogre - Tank type, Low mobility. very high health. Its ability core amps its shield to absorb twice as much damage.

The only way to use the other titans in the beta is through burn cards. You can get titan specific burn cards by completing titan specific challenges (traveling X distance in a titan gets you stryder card)

Comment: "unlimited dashing for a short time", can you rephrase that? It's unclear.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to? Titans can dash to quickly dodge/move. but 1-3 times (depending on the type) until it needs to recharge. the Stryder Core ability allows it to dash around indefinitely until the Core cools. dash != sprint. dashing is more like lunging or dodging.

Comment: Oh I see, I completely missed the part about the ability core. I didn't play enough to get the burn card so I was unsure what you meant. Perhaps "Its ability core allows unlimited dashing for the duration"?

Answer (score 1):

There are currently 3 different titans available:

- Atlas - balanced armor and mobility
- Ogre - best armor
- Stryder - best mobility

More information at the wiki page: [Titans](http://titanfall.wikia.com/wiki/Titans)

You can use the [Reserve Ogre](http://titanfall.wikia.com/wiki/Reserve_Ogre) Burn Card to get the armored one.

I am not sure if you can affect the titan type in the titan customisation.

Answer (score 0):

During the beta, the only way to access different titan chassises is to use the appropriate burn card.